# How to always show the same URL in JSF 2.0?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm making my term paper and I have some doubts in my way.

Now my main question is: how to always shoe the same URL to users using JSF 2.0 (Apache Tomcat 7, JSF 2.0, Java 6)?

I have dozens of pages, one of login, others with the features of my website, but I want that just one URL be showed to users. **What I want is:**

```
If user go to login page, the url will be:
mypage.com/

If user login with succesfull, the url will be:
mypage.com/ 

If user do any thing inside system, the url will be:
mypage.com/
```

Note that I always want "render" (this is the right meaning?) a different page, but show the same URL to user.

**How I can do that? [Page Forward](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-page-forward-vs-page-redirect/)?**

Comment: You seem to be writing a paper on *How should one never use a web framework judging from the JSF experience* or *The things web developer should never do*. Good luck!

Comment: @Fernando, I think the link you provided explains it, doesn't it?

Comment: @skuntsel Thanks for your reply, I think better about that. If you want, please answer this question with your tip (to help other people to (not) do that). I will accept it because this is the right way to do the things :P

Comment: @XtremeBiker I don't know, because I want the best method to do that, but as skuntsel said, this is not a good thing to do. Thanks likewise :)

Comment: Hope my answer will hepl you ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't necessarily mean it's a bad thing to maintain your url static.

If you use **page forward**, you're currently in other url, even browser's address bar doesn't reflect that. With **page redirect** (POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern) you get the new url on it, however [it requires one step more](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=181) from http protocol point of view, so it's a bit slower. Both of them allow you going to an specific view with its url (bookmarkable app) and also are considered into JSF navigation case based system.

What actually could be considered a pitfall, but could be used depending on the case, is to have your application's main frame (could be [the main template](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqxp.html) from JSF's point of view) in an url and just **rerender some of its content via ajax**. That doesn't allow you to have bookmarkable pages, however it could be even faster than performing a page forward if you're interested in maintaining many parts of your view with the same content.

Comment: Thanks for explain @Xtreme Biker , this will help a lot of people. :P